# Pandas Reference Error

Tags: python, pandas

My coding:

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv('some.csv',index_col=0)
>>> temp = df
>>> df.columns
Index([u'Open', u'Close'], dtype='object')
>>> temp.loc[:,'Date'] = temp.index # Line (A)
>>> df.columns
Index([u'Open', u'Close', u'Date'], dtype='object')
>>> temp.columns
Index([u'Open', u'Close', u'Date'], dtype='object')
```

After Line (A), Both variable 'df' and temp are same, but i dont think the df should be modified in anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need [`copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) only:

```
temp = df.copy()
```

`temp = df` not create a copy (since python is a referential language) and just makes two references pointing to the same object.